# Data Structures and Algorithms implementation-Dictionary

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

I have implemented Dictionary with Vector(Array). In array i store a String data. Now i have get position Method. But i want to retrieve data at some position. what will be the method? Thank you.

```
private int findpositionProfile(String smkey){      
    DictionaryProfile p = new DictionaryProfile(smkey,null);  
    return data.getposi(p);  
}


public Profile getProfile(int i){
//  DictionaryProfile p = new DictionaryProfile(null,null);
    return data.get(i);
```

this is not working

```
public class Dictionary {

private Vector data;
private Vector data1;

public Dictionary() {
    data = new Vector(100);
    data1 = new Vector(100);
}

public void addProfile(String smkey, Profile smvalue) {
    DictionaryProfile d = new DictionaryProfile(smkey, smvalue);
    if (data.getposi(d) == -1) {
        data.addLast(d);
    }
    data.replace(d);
}
public void addCorporate(String smkey, CorporateProfile smvalue) {
    DictionaryCorporate d = new DictionaryCorporate(smkey, smvalue);
    if (data1.getposi(d) == -1) {
        data1.addLast(d);
    }
    data1.replace(d);
}

private int findpositionProfile(String smkey) {
    DictionaryProfile p = new DictionaryProfile(smkey,null);
    return data.getposi(p);
}
public CorporateProfile getCorporate(int i){
    return data.get(i);
}
public Profile getProfile(int i){
    DictionaryProfile p = new DictionaryProfile(null,null);
    return data.get(i);
}
```

My dictionaryPair::

```
public class DictionaryProfile implements Comparable
    {
    private String userName ;
    private Profile completeProfile ;

    public DictionaryProfile ( String name,Profile p){
        userName = name;
        completeProfile = p;
    }

    public String getUserName(){
        return userName;
    }

    public Profile getProfile(){
        return completeProfile;
    }

    public void setUsename ( String newname ){
        userName= newname;
    }

    public void setProfile ( Profile pro ){
        completeProfile = pro;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object obj){
        DictionaryProfile dp = (DictionaryProfile) obj;
        return (this.getUserName()).compareTo(dp.getUserName());
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "it's not working"?  What happens?

Comment: Would you please elaborate more? Add a bit more code maybe?

Comment: Its error(saying: cannot covert to Profile type )

Comment: It means that whatever you're trying to get from data is not a Profile. How did you define your array?

Comment: Ok, is there any special reason why you are using vectors? You should change that for an ArrayList or LinkedList... Vectors are really really old. It seems like you're trying to cast an Object into a Profile. I recommend you to take a look at Java Generics :-)

Comment: It looks like whatever resource you're using for Java APIs is literally 15 years old.

Comment: Ok, thank u.. I will have a look

Answer (score 1):

No one should be using the JDK 1.0 vintage `Vector` class.  This doesn't look like a generic `Dictionary` ADT to me.

This method makes no sense whatsoever:

```
public Profile getProfile(int i){
    DictionaryProfile p = new DictionaryProfile(null,null);
    return data.get(i);
}
```

The local variable p is instantiated, never used, and eligible for GC when it goes out of scope.  Data is a `Vector` holding type `Object`.  Where do you expect to get a `Profile` from?

This code makes no sense.

This will work, unless you pass an index that's out of bounds.

```
public Profile getProfile(int i){
    return (Profile) data.get(i);
}
```

None of this describes how a `Dictionary` works.  It's a synonym for a `Map`, which has a key/value pair.  Your code isn't doing that.  Doesn't use generics for key or value.  Why would you do this instead of just using a `Map<K, V>`?

I think you should start with this:

```
package collections;   

public interface Dictionary<K, V> {
    V get(K key);
    V put(K key, V value);
    boolean containsKey(K key);
    int size();    
}
```

Your keys ought to be immutable.

This is what I would consider the minimal interface for a proper `Dictionary`.

Here's an implementation that uses backing `ArrayList`:

```
package collections;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Implementation of a Dictionary interface
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 12/30/2015.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538520/data-structures-and-algorithms-implementation-dictionary/34538668?noredirect=1#comment56819702_34538668
 */
public class DictionaryImpl<K, V> implements Dictionary<K, V> {

    private List<K> keys;
    private List<V> values;

    public DictionaryImpl() {
        this.keys = new ArrayList<>();
        this.values = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public V get(K key) {
        V value = null;
        if (this.keys.contains(key)) {
            int index = this.getIndex(key);
            if (index != -1) {
                value = this.values.get(index);
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        V previousValue = null;
        if (this.keys.contains(key)) {
            previousValue = this.get(key);
        }
        this.keys.add(key);
        this.values.add(value);
        return previousValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(K key) {
        return this.keys.contains(key);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return this.keys.size();
    }

    private int getIndex(K keyToFind) {
        int index = -1;
        if (this.keys.contains(keyToFind)) {
            for (K key : this.keys) {
                ++index;
                if (key.equals(keyToFind)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```

Here's a Junit test to prove that it's all working:

```
package collections;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Junit test for Dictionary
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 12/30/2015.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538520/data-structures-and-algorithms-implementation-dictionary/34538668?noredirect=1#comment56819702_34538668
 */
public class DictionaryTest {

    private Dictionary<String, Integer> testDictionary;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.testDictionary = new DictionaryImpl<>();
        this.testDictionary.put("foo", 17);
        this.testDictionary.put("bar", 23);
        this.testDictionary.put("baz", 31);
        this.testDictionary.put("bat", 41);
    }

    @Test
    public void testContainsKey_True() {
        String [] keys = { "foo", "bar", "baz", "bat" };
        for (String key : keys) {
            Assert.assertTrue(String.format("Should have contained key '%s'", key), this.testDictionary.containsKey(key));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testContainsKey_False() {
        String [] keys = { "dopey", "sleepy", "doc", "sneezy" };
        for (String key : keys) {
            Assert.assertTrue(String.format("Should not have contained key '%s'", key), !this.testDictionary.containsKey(key));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet_Success() {
        String [] keys = { "foo", "bar", "baz", "bat" };
        Integer [] values = { 17, 23, 31, 41 };
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
            Assert.assertEquals(String.format("Should have returned value %d for key '%s'", values[i], keys[i]), values[i], this.testDictionary.get(keys[i]));
        }
    }


    @Test
    public void testGet_NoSuchKey() {
        String [] keys = { "dopey", "sleepy", "doc", "sneezy" };
        for (String key : keys) {
            Assert.assertNull(String.format("Should have returned null for key '%s'", key), this.testDictionary.get(key));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSize() {
        int expected = 4;
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, this.testDictionary.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: I know i am wrong.... Thats what I wanted to understand. This is what is coming to my mind now. But i know this is wrong

Comment: I've told you a lot: How to fix that error, what a Dictionary really is.  That ought to send you in a better direction.